# php prepared statement with on duplicate key update - access original value, if there was one, for conditional tests?

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb, prepared-statement

I have run into a unique situation and I am not sure if this is possible or not.  I need to access the original value of `update` (if there was one) and pass it to a function to determine if I keep the original value (if there was one), change it, or insert a default value in the case the entry never existed?

Is my only option running another query to retrieve that value (if it exists) or is there a way to access the value in my binding (if it exists) to use in a function to determine the value inserted/updated?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO accounts (
            account_id,
            version,
            update
        )
        VALUES (
            :account_id,
            :version,
            :update
       )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        version = VALUE(version),
        update = VALUE(update)
");

//bindings
$binding = array(
    'account_id' => 'some id',
    'version' => 'some version',
    'update' => ### is there a way to access the original value (if there was one)?  I'd like to pass this to a function to determine what value I insert/update into the db
);

$stmt->execute($binding);
```

Comment: why not do a `select` first ?

Comment: I don't know if MySQL and MariaDB are still similar enough or not, but MySQL allows you to pass a value to `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. I wonder if you could do something like `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE update = VALUE(LAST_INSERT_ID(update))`. If that worked, you could probably get it off the `$db->lastInsertId()` after execute.